# Azure Speech SDK stopping the speech recognization after 4minutes of inactivity with status : Service Timeout

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I am using Azure speech SDK for speech-text translation functionality. The service is doing its job of translation however after 4minutes of inactivity the service is calling cancel event which stops the speech recognition with the status service Timeout, Due to service inactivity the client buffer size exceeded. Resetting the buffer.

Comment: Could you please add more details about the region that you are trying?

Comment: Hi,I am using eastus region.

Comment: Can you please confirm are you still facing this issue?

Comment: yes stil I am facing this issue

Comment: Could you please inform which version of Azure Speech SDK you are using? Also could you please provide logs from the SDK by following these instructions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-logging

Comment: just in case, doublecheck if bitrate/channels/bits correspond between settings and stream